# Finding whether two geo-coordinates lie on the same road

Tags: geolocation, reverse-geocoding

Given two geo-coordinates in (latitude,longitude) format, is it 
possible to find out if they lie on the same road? I want to do this 
programatically not visually. 
I can perhaps extract addresses and compare the street name, but since 
streets can change names over a long distance, this solution doesnt 
sem to work :( 
Cheers 
Amarsh

Comment: Could you request a route from point A to point B somewhere? If it comes back with a single direction (as opposed to multiple "turns"), I would _assume_ that it's the same road.

Comment: Great thanks. That sounds like a good idea. Is there a way to make that request programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you could try use routing to determine if a path is "straight" or would require multiple turns.

As for doing it programmatically, you could use Google's map API to request the route. Documentation for this process is located [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#RoutesAndSteps) and an example is located [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/directions-advanced.html) (just use View Source in your browser to examine the code).